# How to expand the tap area of a a stacklayout to occupy the height of a viewcell?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have the following code snippet in XAML:

```
<TableView Intent="Settings">
   <TableRoot>
      <TableSection Title="Card Front Side">
         <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout x:Name="englishSide" Padding="20,0,20,0"
                         BackgroundColor="Red"
                         Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
               <Label Text="English" XAlign="Center"/>
               <Image x:Name="englishImage" Source="check.png" 
                      HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" IsVisible="false" />
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
       </TableSection>
   </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

In my C# code I have the following code to handle the tap event:

```
englishSide.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
{
   NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
   Command = new Command(() =>
   {
       englishImage.IsVisible = true;
       App.Database.UpdateSettings((int)Lang.English, "CardFrontSide");
   })
});
```

Now when I tap on the row I noticed that it doesn't respond to my tap immediately. Then I realised the area where the tapped event could be apply is not occupying the whole height of the row as shown in the image below (the area with red background).

[image]

Can anyone let me know how can I make it occupy the whole row/ViewCell height without changing the height of the ViewCell? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `StackLayout`'s `VerticalOptions` is set to `"Center"`, which means *"See that space over there? Just get there somewhere in the middle thank you*".
Which means that the StackLayout won't take any more space than needed.

If you want you `StackLayout` to fill the cell's height (which is defined by `ListView.RowHeight`), you need to set it to `FillAndExpand` (You can try the different values, I'm unsure here if `CenterAndExpand` or `Fill` would be enough).

If `CenterAndExpand` does not work, you may wrap your `StackLayout` with `VerticalOptions="Center"` in another `StackLayout` with `FillAndExpand` so that you keep your text vertically centered:

```
<TableView Intent="Settings">
   <TableRoot>
      <TableSection Title="Card Front Side">
         <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         x:Name="englishSide"
                         Padding="20,0,20,0"
                         BackgroundColor="Red">
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                 <Label Text="English" XAlign="Center"/>
                 <Image x:Name="englishImage" Source="check.png" 
                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" IsVisible="false" />
              </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
       </TableSection>
   </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

Comment: Thanks @Thibault. But this doesn't seem to work. The `FillAndExpand` on the outside `StackLayout` does the trick of occupying the `ViewCell`'s height. But the problem is the inner `StackLayout` with `VerticalOptions="Center` is not working. Text is no longer centered.

Comment: My apologizes @iamsophia , I had not tested my code :). Now I've tested and edited my answer and the only thing you need to change is the `VerticalOptions` of the inner StackLayout from `Center` to `CenterAndExpand`.